# Post methods doesn't work in Django 1.8, Python3 TypeError: can't concat bytes to str

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

When I try to use forms with a POST method, I'm getting a TypeError: can't concat bytes to str. It's not only happening when I use my forms, but when I input login/password for admin panel too.

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://photofresh.site/blog/post_new/

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 3.5.0
Installed Applications:

    ['django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'bootstrap3',
     'blog']

Installed Middleware:

    ['django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response

      125. response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py" in process_view

      174. request_csrf_token = request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '')

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py" in _get_post

      137. self._load_post_and_files()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/request.py" in _load_post_and_files

      272. self._post, self._files = QueryDict(self.body, encoding=self._encoding), MultiValueDict()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/request.py" in body

      233. self._body = self.read()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/request.py" in read

      292. return self._stream.read(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py" in read

      51. result = self.buffer + self._read_limited()

Exception Type: TypeError at /blog/post_new/
Exception Value: can't concat bytes to str
```

Here is my HTML form. I know that it's better to use Django Forms, but this particular example worked perfectly fine while I was using it with a runserver command on my computer.

```
<form action="{% url 'blog:post_new' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
Text:<br>
<input type="text" name="text">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

view.py:

```
def post_new(request):
posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date')
_name = request.POST['name']
_text = request.POST['text']
_date = timezone.now()
p = Post(name=_name, text=_text, date=_date)
p.save()
return render(request, 'blog/base.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Comment: Please show us your form, view and template

Comment: @ascripter I updated what you asked, but it should be noticed that the standard admin panel has this problem too.

Comment: Looking at your problem its look like you have an encoding problem.

Comment: @DikshaJiwane unfortunately it's not, because the problem occurs in admin panel too (login and password are in english)